# ext js 4 window don't want change options at first time

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have window

```
Ext.define('SD.view.SDDetail', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias: 'widget.sddetailwindow',
    height: 620,
    width: 850,
    layout: 'fit',
    border: false,
    modal: true,

    isDemandReadOnly: true,
    changeStatusOnly: true,
    isNew: true,
 initComponent: function () {}}
```

when i open it i want change options isDemandReadOnly isNew changeStatusOnly like this, 
this code from controller

```
, onAdd: function (item) {
        var win = this.getSdDetailWindow({
            isDemandReadOnly: false,
            changeStatusOnly: false,
            isNew: false
        });

        win.show();
}
```

but at first time isDemandReadOnly isNew changeStatusOnly dont change it values
at second it is all ok
why at first time my values not change?

Comment: Why do you pass the object to getSdDetailWindow()? May you replace the code with explicitly getting the SdDetailWindow then changing its configs?

Answer (score 0):

Create your component with those properties set

```
var win = Ext.create('SD.view.SDDetail', {
    isDemandReadOnly: false,
    changeStatusOnly: false,
    isNew: false
})
```

or set them after your getter's call

```
var win = this.getSdDetailWindow();

win.isDemandReadOnly = false;
win.changeStatusOnly = false;
win.isNew = false;
```

Comment: var win = Ext.create('SD.view.SDDetail', {
    isDemandReadOnly: false,
    changeStatusOnly: false,
    isNew: false
})  this work, but i can't do this this.getSdDetailWindow() only with Ext.getCmp('') :(